# Closure-compiler didn't flatten this if statement into a "guard" using &&

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

I don't understand why CC didn't codegolf this further. I frequently write with "guard" statements like `var x = obj.fun && obj.fun();` for example. But CC doesn't reduce an `if` into a "guard".

Are the compiled js and expected js actually different?

Uncompiled source:

```
window.test = function () {
  var ret = false;
  if (Math.random) {
    ret = Math.random() < 0.5;
  }
  return ret;
}
```

Command

```
npx google-closure-compiler \
--compilation_level ADVANCED \
--js test.js \
--js_output_file out.js
```

Compiled output (prettified):

```
window.test = function() {
  var a = !1;
  Math.random && (a = 0.5 > Math.random());
  return a;
};
```

Expected output ("What I would have done"):

```
window.test = function () {
  return Math.random && 0.5 > Math.random();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This code returns `undefined` if the Math.random function does not exists:

```
return Math.random && 0.5 > Math.random();
```

I think that there may be a difference between returning `false` and returning `undefined`.

Comment: So why not `return !!Math.random && 0.5 > Math.random();`

Comment: Because it takes more operations at runtime maybe. Make a test, modify your original code to set `ret = undefined` and see what it does.

Comment: `window.test=function(){var a;Math.random&&(a=.5>Math.random());return a};`, where I would have written it as `window.test=function(){if(Math.random)return .5>Math.random())};` again removing the variable.

Comment: You're probably on the right track, that it may be slower. I have a hard time seeing how that's the case, but V8 is a strange beast. I'll leave it at that.

Comment: Many things may happen there: 1. The compiler thinks that returning undefined and not returning a value is different (I personally don't know if there is a difference). It could also be a distinction for future-proof compatibility. 2. The runtime tests if `Math.random` is truthy in any case, but `!!Math.random` may still be an additional operation to be interpreted by the runtime.

Comment: You are giving the compiler too much credit.  It simply doesn't have a transformation that would do this.  If you avoid setting "ret" twice, you get:

  `return Math.random?.5>Math.random():!1`

But the compiler doesn't "know" how to transform that into:

  `return !!Math.random && .5>Math.random();`